# how to move marker in google map, when i click anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

how to make : if i click some where place in google map, the marker will appear on it, if i click other place, the marker will change/move to new place.

I think, will create event onClick, but i confused how to start.

here my code :

this code is only the basic of google map, Map is already appear.

```
<script>
function loadmap()
{
var watchID = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}
function onSuccessjalan(position) 
{

var element = document.getElementById('peta');
var lat=position.coords.latitude;
var lang=position.coords.longitude;
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lang);


 var myMapOptions = {
   zoom: 12
   ,center: myLatlng
   ,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
 };
 var theMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myMapOptions);
 var image = "images/loctag.png";





 var myOptions = {
  content: ""
 ,disableAutoPan: false
 ,maxWidth: 0
 ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, -110)
 ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(140, 110)
 ,zIndex: null
 ,boxStyle: { 
  background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
  ,opacity: 0.90
 }
 ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
 ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
 ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
 ,isHidden: false
 ,pane: "floatPane"
 ,enableEventPropagation: false
 };




}
</script>
```

i need output like this screenshoot below

[image]

[image]

Comment: The documentation is a good place to start. Here you go:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain a global reference to the last marker added to the map (the previous marker to be removed). Then handle the logic in the click listener.

I included this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/3183/) to show how it works

```
/*
 * declare map as a global variable
 */
var map;
var previousMarker;
/*
 * use google maps api built-in mechanism to attach dom events
 */
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {

  /*
   * create map
   */
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

    map.addListener('click', function(e) {
        if (previousMarker)
        previousMarker.setMap(null);
        placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
    });
    return marker;


  /*
   * add markers to map
   */
  var marker0 = createMarker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
    map: map,
    icon: "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_GZzKwf6g1o8/S6xwK6CSghI/AAAAAAAAA98/_iA3r4Ehclk/s1600/marker-green.png"
  }, "<h1>Marker 0</h1><p>This is the home marker.</p>");
});



function placeMarker(position, map) {
    previousMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map
    });
    map.setPosition(position);
}
```

Comment: Thank you..its really helping. But how to remove first marker, if i continue to click somewhere ( if i click somewhere, marker will appear, if i click other place , first marker will removed, and will appear in new place)

Comment: @Def I updated my answer and added a fiddle to show functionality.